# JQuery width() returning wrong value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am in a scenario like this:

We have two similar popup windows, and such popup windows are generated by a factory (in Javascript) so that they share same common events & functions. One of them is our custom resize function named `resizeFormRowService`. It will get called when the browser window fires the `resize` event.

As the popup window is in a structure like repeating

```
<div class="row">
    <div> //label </div>
    <div> //data  </div>
</div>
```

The `resizeFormRowService` first get the width of the parent div with class `row`, then set it's first div child (which is label) to a fixed width like 140px, and set second div's width to "parent - first child". All are done by JQuery (as shown below)

---

I found that there is a strange behavior on one of the popup in Chrome (I am comparing two similar popup windows as stated).

The calculated width of the second child div (which is data) is 5px more than the other popup's corresponding field. So I log something in `resizeFormRowService` to trace what's going on.

```js
StandardTemplatePopup.prototype.resizeFormRowService = function () {
  var self = this;
  var $popUp = self.getPopup();

  ...
  
  var $rows = $popUp.find('.row');
  $rows.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $firstDiv = $this.find('div:first');
    var $secondDiv = $this.find('div:eq(1)');
    var labelColWidth = self.options('labelColWidth');

    // labelColWidth is something we can config, so both popup firstDiv's width is the same
    // so I think the problem must be in $this.width()
    $firstDiv.width(labelColWidth);
    
    //Add by me, want to see which row is this 
    console.log($this);
    //Add by me, see this row's width
    console.log($this.width());

    var width = $this.width() - $firstDiv.outerWidth() - 0.5;
    $secondDiv.width(width);
  });
  ...
};
```

Running this on both popup windows, one log `270px` while the other one log `265px`!  So I try to see which rows are they, at this point I think maybe there is some scripts within the first popup window changing the row's margin / padding and thus changing its width, but surprisingly it's not the case

*Here is first popup*

[image]

*Here is the second popup*

[image]

As shown, the second child div's calculated width differ by 5px, but the parent's row width is **exactly the same**, which is contradicting what I logged in the `resizeFormRowService`!

So my question is: are there any known issues of JQuery width() which lead to my problem? If no, then any advice pointing to potential cause is appreciated.

**EDITED:**

I hope this may hint someone, one of my teammates, by trial & error, adding an empty div at the end of the first popup window

```
<div class="col-xs-12">&nbsp;</div>
```

Then everything goes fine...both popup windows will resize correctly.

---

*PS1: The smaller result: 265px is the correct and expected result*

*PS2: The height difference in the images is due to the wrongly calculated width of the second child div which makes content too wide to show in one line, so the height is auto-increased*

Comment: Do you use margins and/or paddings? Have you tried to use `outerWidth(true)` instead?

Comment: @Babydead For first question I think no, I just go and verify again, we do not explicitly set margin & padding, at least not in the parent 'row' div.  For second question, I did not try as I did not even log the firstdiv.outerWidth, the parent div width itself already seems strange to me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to put this in an answer because comments aren't very insightful.

To me, it would seem that your calculations are too fast and don't keep to any pre-set values. Something like say, a CSS transition would 100% surely mess it up for you. I personally would code it more like this (being a front-ender myself)

```
$rows.each(function () {
  var $this= $(this);
  var $firstDiv = $('div:first', $this);
  var $secondDiv = $('div:eq(1)', $this);
  var labelColWidth = self.options('labelColWidth');

  // labelColWidth is something we can config, so both popup firstDiv's width is the same
  // so I think the problem must be in $this.width()
  $firstDiv.width(labelColWidth);

  //Add by me, want to see which row is this 
  console.log($this);
  //Add by me, see this row's width
  console.log($this.width());

  //why recalculate the $firstDiv.width when you have labelColWidth?
  //try to avoid simple names like "width" for prevention of double naming
  var newWidth = $this.width() - labelColWidth - 0.5;
  $secondDiv.width(newWidth);
});
```

-- I should mention, Selectors like `div:first` and `div:eq(1)` tend to break when you insert things like `: after` or `: before`. I would recommend you use classes instead.